# How to append the filenames of randomly selected images used in creating a single image to a csv file?

Tags: python, image, numpy, csv

Thank you massively to Paul M who posted the following code in response to my first query on how to compile a "stack" of randomly selected images into a unique image:

```
from pathlib import Path
from random import choice

layers = [list(Path(directory).glob("*.png")) for directory in ("bigcircle/", "mediumcircle/")]

selected_paths = [choice(paths) for paths in layers]

img = Image.new("RGB", (4961, 4961), color=(0, 220, 15))
for path in selected_paths:
    layer = Image.open(str(path), "r")
    img.paste(layer, (0, 0), layer)
```

I have the code sat in a `for _ in itertools.repeat(None, num):` where `num` defines the number of different images being generated. I end the loop with the following to save each image with a unique (incremental) file name:

```
i = 0
while os.path.exists("Finished Pieces/image %s.png" % i):
    i += 1
img.save("Finished Pieces/image %s.png" % i,)
```

So far, so good. The challenge I'm struggling with now is how to append to a `data.csv` file with the details of each image created.

For example, in loop 1 `bigcircle1.png` is selected from `bigcircle/` folder and `mediumcircle6.png` from `mediumcircle/`, loop 2 uses `bigcircle3.png` and `mediumcircle2.png`, and so on. At the end of this loop the `data.csv` file would read:

```
Filename,bigcircle,mediumcircle
image 0,bigcircle1.png,mediumcircle6.png
image 1,bigcircle3.png,mediumcircle2.png
```

I've tried the following, which I know wouldn't give the desired result, but which I thought might be a good start for me to run and tweak until right, but it doesn't generate any output (and I am importing `numpy` as `np`):

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', [p for p in zip(img, layer)], delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
```

If it's not too much of an ask, ideally the first iteration of the loop would create `data.csv` and store the first record, with the second iteration onwards appending this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me again ;)

I think it would make sense to split up the functionality of the program into separate functions. I would start maybe with a function called something like `discover_image_paths`, which discovers (via `glob`) all image paths. It might make sense to store the paths according to what kind of circle they represent - I'm envisioning a dictionary with `"big"` and `"medium"` keys, and lists of paths as associated values:

```
def discover_image_paths():
    from pathlib import Path
    keys = ("bigcircle", "mediumcircle")
    return dict(zip(keys, (list(Path(directory).glob("*.png")) for directory in (key+"/" for key in keys))))


def main():

    global paths

    paths = discover_image_paths()
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

In the terminal:

```
>>> paths["bigcircle"]
[WindowsPath('bigcircle/big1.png'), WindowsPath('bigcircle/big2.png'), WindowsPath('bigcircle/big3.png')]
>>> paths["mediumcircle"]
[WindowsPath('mediumcircle/med1.png'), WindowsPath('mediumcircle/med2.png'), WindowsPath('mediumcircle/med3.png')]
>>>
```

As you can see, to test the script, I created some dummy image files - three for each category.

Extending this by adding a function to generate an output image (given an iterable of paths to combine and an output file name) and a main loop to generate `num_images` number of images (sorry, I'm not familiar with numpy):

```
def generate_image(paths, color, output_filename):
    from PIL import Image

    dimensions = (4961, 4961)

    image = Image.new("RGB", dimensions, color=color)
    for path in paths:
        layer = Image.open(path, "r")
        image.paste(layer, (0, 0), layer)
    image.save(output_filename)

def discover_image_paths(keys):
    from pathlib import Path
    return dict(zip(keys, (list(Path(directory).glob("*.png")) for directory in (key+"/" for key in keys))))

def main():

    from random import choice, choices
    from csv import DictWriter

    field_names = ["filename", "color"]
    keys = ["bigcircle", "mediumcircle"]
    paths = discover_image_paths(keys)

    num_images = 5

    with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = DictWriter(file, fieldnames=field_names+keys)
        writer.writeheader()

        for image_no in range(1, num_images + 1):
            selected_paths = {key: choice(category_paths) for key, category_paths in paths.items()}
            file_name = "output_{}.png".format(image_no)

            color = tuple(choices(range(0, 256), k=3))
            
            generate_image(map(str, selected_paths.values()), color, file_name)

            row = {**dict(zip(field_names, [file_name, color])), **{key: path.name for key, path in selected_paths.items()}}

            writer.writerow(row)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Example output in the CSV:

```
filename,color,bigcircle,mediumcircle
output_1.png,"(49, 100, 190)",big3.png,med1.png
output_2.png,"(228, 37, 227)",big2.png,med3.png
output_3.png,"(251, 14, 193)",big1.png,med1.png
output_4.png,"(35, 12, 196)",big1.png,med3.png
output_5.png,"(62, 192, 170)",big2.png,med2.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you've gone to, Paul. Unfortunately I can't get this to work. I'm not getting any error messages, but the code is completing very quickly and not producing the images or appending to the CSV. I'm on Mac and when I check my paths in the terminal WindowsPath is replaced with PoxisPath. Otherwise I can't detect what the issue may be.

Comment: Sorry Paul, my mistake. I had the second block of code immediately below the first block, so the programme was ending at the first 'sys.exit(main())'. When I run them as separate scripts it works exactly as expected and as I was looking for. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Just one last thing. How would one also save the color in (r, g, b) format in the CSV between filename and bigcircle, please? I'm planning to make this random for each image (which you'll be pleased to know, I can do!) Thank you, again.

Comment: No worries. I've edited my answer - keep in mind though that writing a plain tuple to a CSV (for the RGB color channels) will introduce double-quotes (since you're inserting additional commas). This is done to prevent the file from being impossible to parse. It's something you'll probably have to take into account, though, when you're reading from the file - you'll have to do a string-to-tuple-of-integers conversion.