# how to stack input *.tif files to a new output.tif raster file

Tags: python, raster, tiff

I want to stack raster files (*.tiff) and create a new raster (*.tiff).
The input raster files are RGB and need to be combined without color change.
Can anyone help me to stack them and combine a new RGB file?

Example to clear things up:
inputfile1.tif contains a red A
inputfile2.tif contains a blue C
inputfile3.tif contains a green S
... ...
inputfile15.tif contains a purple X

outputfile.tif contains red A, blue C, green S, ..., purple X

[This is how I want to stack the raster data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1mhj.jpg)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a folder named `tiffs` with the following images:

`inputfile01.tif`

`inputfile02.tif`

`inputfile03.tif`

`inputfile15.tif`

The following script uses the third-party module `PIL` to open your `.tif` images, and generates a composite image. You didn't specify how they should be stitched together, so this script just puts them next to each other in a single row, from left to right. It inserts them in the order in which `pathlib.Path.glob` discovered the image file paths - in this case in lexicographical order (that's why I added a leading zero to the file names where normally there would be just a single digit).

```
def main():

    from PIL import Image
    from pathlib import Path
    from itertools import accumulate

    paths = Path("tiffs").glob("*.tif")

    images = list(map(Image.open, paths))

    offsets = list(accumulate((image.size[0] for image in images), initial=0))

    width = offsets[-1]
    height = max(image.size[1] for image in images)

    composite = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))

    for x_offset, image in zip(offsets, images):
        composite.paste(image, (x_offset, 0))
        image.close()

    composite.show()
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

[image]

This should work for any number of images, with any file name.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/LZbyN6N/example.jpg
This is how i want to stack the Images

Comment: Take a look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68277197/10987432) I posted to create a composite of stacked layers.